# How to model a simple use case diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

suppose you have to do a Use Case Diagram for this simple problem (that is part of a much bigger exercise i am doing):

a registered user (of a web application) can search for tourist attractions in two ways: by category (for example: museums, parks, theaters, archaeological sites) or by location (city, county).

How should i model this UCD?

The most simple way would be: the actor (registered user), two use cases (search tourist attraction by category and search by location), the secondary actor (the server of the web application, which would process the query and send back the results).

My concern is that in this way the four categories and the two type of locations would not be present in the use case.

I was thinking of using the "extend" relationship. For example, i would add a use case named "Search parks" that extends the use case "Search by category". The extension point would be the event that the user chooses to search for parks.

Or i could use an inheritance relationship between the "Search by category" and "Search parks"...mmmm...i am a little confused...

How would you model this little problem using USD??

Thank you,
Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to realize, that Use Case Diagrams aren't substitute for actual (written) Use Cases. Use Case descriptions contain many important details, which are omitted in Use Case diagrams. Use Case diagrams are good for depicting hierarchies of actors, associated use cases and relationships between use cases, but nothing more.

Another important thing is to realize what an use case actually is. Good way to think about them is to find a goal of an actor, which he/she wants to achieve with help from the system. Achieving this goal should give the actor some business value. My point is, that from what you described, registered user might want to search for a sightseeing and/or buy entry tickets. So this is his goal and this should be a an use case, don't confuse use cases with functionality/features like different ways of searching etc.

In your first suggestion you have two use cases, which differ only in data (e.g. it might be just different choice from a combo box in a form). Such differences, if they don't influence the way the system and actors interact, are described separately from the use cases in a data glossary, which you reference in your use case. This way you avoid many unnecessary details in use case descriptions. If on the other hand, the steps in the description change (e.g. when registečred user chooses location system gives him/her an option to select another registered user as a friend and pre-selects favourite locations of both or something like that...), you can capture this by using alternatives/extensions.

You mention the system you are developing as the secondary actor. Don't forget, the system under development is an implicit actor and is not shown diagrams as a separate actor. Use boundary box (rectangle encompassing use cases excluding actors) to depict scope of your system.

Finally to your concern. These are all just details about the data, which are not part of an use case. You can capture those details in text (by namicng all categories etc.) using the data glossary as mentioned above. If you think the structure and relations between data is important and needs to be captured using diagrams, you can use class diagrams to create data/domain models.

Last note about use case relationships - don't use them if you don't have to. They are often hard to understand and vaguely defined. Never ever use them to decompose the functionality, that is up to design, not analysis with use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I hate depicting Search in a use case. There are simply too many variables. It's like trying to write a use case for using a browser.

Search is a good candidate for early prototyping supplemented with business rules.